# Is this a unique property of power functions?

Tags: functions, exponentiation

I want to find all continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that
$$\forall s \in \mathbb{R}^+: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+: \frac{f(x)}{f(s x)} = \frac{f(1)}{f(s)}$$
I know that scaled power functions $f(x)=b x^a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ have this property. I would like to find a continuous function $f$ that has this property although it is not a scaled power function of prove that no such function exists.

(edited after reading Greg Martin's comment)

Comment: Note that by choosing $x=1$ you can write $c$ in terms of $f$ and $s$, so there are really only two quantifiers. After taking logarithms, this problem reduces to [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), and the answer depends on whether you restrict $f$ to be continuous or not. (Another comment: $f(x)=bx^a$ is a solution for any $b>0$ as well.)

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for the helpful pointers! Using the rewrite you suggested I get $f(s x)=f(s)f(x)/f(1)$ which is almost the multiplicative Cauchy's functional equation which can be reduced to the additive one. I still have to think about the effect of dividing by $f(1)$ but as you pointed out it leads to the additional solution $f(x)=b x^a$. We can assume that $f$ is continuous. I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: Divide by $f(1)$ to get $\tfrac{f(sx)}{f(1)} = \tfrac{f(s)}{f(1)}\, \tfrac{f(x)}{f(1)}$. Now you have the multiplicative Cauchy's functional equation with $g(x)=f(x)/f(1)$

Comment: @jjagmath Perfect, that proves every continous $f$ needs to be propertional to an exponential function and therefore be of the form $f(x) = b x^a$

Comment: Careful, $f(x) = x^a$ is **not an exponential function**, that would be $a^x$, a very different function. $x^a$ is a **power function**.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant 